# How to stop playing a sound that is played with the PlaySound() function?

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, playsound

I played a sound using the `PlaySound()` function. How can I stop playing that sound? Is there any function that can do that job?

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v=vs.85)) has the following to say about the `pszSound` parameter:

> If this parameter is `NULL`, any currently playing waveform sound is stopped.

Following that contract you simply call

```cpp
::PlaySound(nullptr, nullptr, 0);
```

to stop playing.

Comment: Note: this requires the original sound to be played using the `SND_ASYNC` flag, per the same documentation: "*`SND_ASYNC` The sound is played asynchronously and PlaySound returns immediately after beginning the sound. **To terminate an asynchronously played waveform sound, call PlaySound with pszSound set to NULL**.*".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
PlaySound(NULL, NULL, 0);
```